# Force Pixi.js WebGl to use a new canvas always to solve a bug appearing after page reloaded without browser cache cleared

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, pixi.js

My Pixi.js "game" draws ok and works very well, when the webpage (see a temporary link in the comments section) is loaded a very 1st time OR in the new Chrome/Incognito view page.  However, always when a page is reloaded, there is this a drawing bug appearing on (webgl) canvas.

This problem does not appear if I keep the Chrome DISABLE CACHE setting enabled from Chrome Developer Tools so it must be cache related.
Canvas cache needs to be cleared to make the canvas to be drawn properly again.

I must assume that there are some cached (webgl) content remaining on client between page re-visits/reloading that is causing this drawing bug on canvas.
Even pressing Shift+reload makes the re-draw bug appear again.

About Pixi WebGl Canvas, I am trying to make a new canvas every time as a fix but it does not seem to help, new one is referred like this, but Pixi always makes its own canvas

```
  r.app = new l.Application({
            backgroundColor: 16777215,
            height: 620,
            width: 1100, clearBeforeRender: true, view :  document.getElementById("canv"&location.search.split('v=')[1])
        })
    },
```

I prefer to force somehow to clear the canvas cache, does it help to use always a new canvas name or to give some canvas options?

Another option would be to not use WebGL mode at all.
How can I force PixiJS never to use WebGL?

Comment: I think we need more info. Given that most pages made with Pixi.js work just fine what are you doing different? Without knowing that how can we help? Can you try to make a minimal repo and put it in the question itself via a [snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: unfortunately, just linking to your code offsite is off topic for stack overflow. You have to put enough code *in the question itself* to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Well the problem is that I don't know what part of the 32K code was causing the issue, maybe I need to rephrase my question to something like: How to force Pixi to reset the canvas always...

Comment: That's one of the main points of making a minimal version. pull out all the parts. Start adding parts back in until it repos the issue. You'll either find the issue yourself or you'll have a minimal version to share. Can you draw a single texture and repo the issue? If not, if you have 2 textures does it repo the issue? Etc, add features until you get a minimal version.

Comment: Thank gman, one question; Would the whole problem be solved by disabling WebGL from PIXI settings? Does the canvas2d have this kind of sprite caching at all?  All what is needed is to get rid of a few items remaining on canvas after page reload.

Comment: WebGL has absolutely no way to cache images. Either image caching is implemented by pixi or the browser. What are you trying to do? Are you loading an image from the same URL but that image is supposedly different? Can't you make an example that just loads and draws one or two images and repos the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Can you plz try this first?

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
```

If it doesn't work, here is my another question.

Were you running the server on your local? Or else, you were working with static html files?
In case you were working with a kind of server you do need to follow the below instruction as per server type.

- [ http://cristian.sulea.net/blog/disable-browser-caching-with-meta-html-tags/ ]

Comment: It did not help, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

well textureCache is created every time you call new PIXI.Texture.fromImage and it checks if it (or baseTexture) is already saved in the cache in order to prevent downloading the texture again and again.... from your server if it is already loaded.

Imagine creating a rain effect and preparing the raindrops in a for loop with i <= 200;
Without texture cache this would mean that you would have to call your server 200 times.
texture cache is created from two elements.

The textureCache and the baseTexture. (Every texture cached has a base texture under it
If you'll remove the textureCache by calling .destroy() this will remove the texture but leave the base texture still in your memory.
Practically this means that if you have a sprite on a stage and you call destroy() on the texture. The sprite uploaded to the stage will still be renderable. But after doing this if you would call the same (previously deleted texture) it would reupload it from server.

Using the destroy(true) method on a texture removes the textureCache and the baseTexture. Practically if you would use this method with true argument on a texture used by a sprite that is on your stage the sprite would become black.
baseTextures are heavily used in WebGl context to speed up calculations with the use of gl methods.

https://github.com/GoodBoyDigital/pixi.js/issues/949#issuecomment-54502749

Comment: Thanks, yes there are sprites, but there are no creatures loaded from server, its just very simple text fonts and a few colors. Is there a way to delete all cached sprites in the begin of page reload?